# Cambiar directorio en python

Tags: python, nginx

Necesito cambiar de directorio para ejecutar un comando, buscando encontré varias alternativas pero ninguna funciona, en todas me sale "No such file or directory". El script lo corro en un servidor, desde nginx. El script que corro está en /var/www/carpeta1/test, y el directorio al que necesito ir es /var/www/carpeta2/subcarpeta

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Shami, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas su funcionamiento. Para realizar preguntas revisa [ask] este documento te ayudará a conocer como realizar correctamente una pregunta y tengas buenas respuestas!, saludos..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas empleando la libreria **os** de python debes conocer el directorio actual de trabajo donde corre tu script, asi:

```
import os

print os.getcwd() #esto te permite conocer el directorio actual
os.chdir("/var/www/carpeta2/subcarpeta") # la ruta absoluta
#una vez ubicado en el directorio adecuado puedes ejecutar el comando
```

Comment: No sabía que tenía que poder en getcwd() para que funcione, supuse que ya se sabía el directorio actual. Gracias !